# i want to download a sample text file attached with jsp

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I have a jsp page where user can upload his details via file. but i need a sample format to show him how he has to enter data into the file.and that sample file must be attached in jsp,so on downloading he will come to know how his upload file should be

Comment: i am sorry, could not interpret your question. can you make it more clear?

Comment: *to keep it simple, I want a sample file to be attached in jsp, so that user can download it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a  tag and post a link to the sample file.

```
<a href="/samples/uploadlikethis.txt">Sample Document</a>
```

Comment: Actually i wanted this to be like,when he clicks on that link i want to download uploadlikethis.txt file

Comment: http://www.codemiles.com/servlets-jsp/jsp-to-download-file-t17.html
This link will help you on that..